# How to load a cell(Price) from another sheet based on Option and Item Selected?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, xlsx, xls

I have an xlsx file with 2 sheets,

**Sheet2** Contains source data/feed filled with "Option", "Item" and "Price" based on options.

```
|-------|--------|--------|
|Option | Item   | Price  |
|-------|--------|--------|
|   2   | Banana |  30    |
|-------|--------|--------|
|   2   | MANGO  |  80    |
|-------|--------|--------|
|   2   | ORANGE |  100   |
|-------|--------|--------|
|   2   | RICE   |  20    |
|-------|--------|--------|
|   3   | Banana |  35    |
|-------|--------|--------|
|   3   | MANGO  |  85    |
|-------|--------|--------|
|   3   | ORANGE |  105   |
|-------|--------|--------|
|   3   | RICE   |  25    |
|-------|--------|--------|
|   4   | Banana |  40    |
|-------|--------|--------|
|   4   | MANGO  |  90    |
|-------|--------|--------|
|   4   | ORANGE |  110   |
|-------|--------|--------|
|   4   | RICE   |  30    |
|-------|--------|--------|
```

**Shee1**

> I need to load only price based on option selected, i.e Option 3 selected, so that Column of price should fill with below value.

```
|--------------|--------|
|       A      |  B     |
|--------------|--------|
|    Option    |    3   |   
|--------------|--------|
|    Banana    |    35  |        
|--------------|--------|
|    MANGO     |    85  |       
|--------------|--------|
|    ORANGE    |    105 |     
|--------------|--------|
|    RICE      |    25  |       
|--------------|--------|
```

Can some one help me to resolve this senario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following sample image, put these formulas into F8:G8,

```
=INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($2:$13)/(A$2:A$13=G$7), ROW(1:1)))
=SUMIFS(C:C, A:A, G$7, B:B, F8)
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image]

Comment: Aggregate must be the most unloved function in Excel. To me it's just hieroglyphs. I have to break out the Excel help on that. :)

Comment: The trick is to use **6** to ignore errors and create errors for anything you don't want. In the above, I've forced #DIV/0! for anything I did not want and <row number>/1 for anything I did want.

Comment: @Jeeped In my case "Option" is in another sheet(Sheet1), how to refer other sheet using SUMIFS?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the support.office.com page for SUMIFS.

Comment: Can you please check what is the error in the formula for one of the price cell. Am I refer sheet reference correctly ?
 =SUMIFS(Sheet2!C:Sheet2!C, Sheet2!A:Sheet2!A,Sheet1!D11,Sheet2!B:Sheet2!B,Sheet1!B16)   I tried follow your SUMIFS formula.

Comment: `Sheet2!C:Sheet2!C` should be `Sheet2!C:C`

Answer (score 2):

Use a pivot table and filter (or use slicers) for the options.

Or use Sumifs() to summarise the data. A pivot table won't require any formulas, just a few clicks.

In the screenshot below, the Sumifs formula in cell J7 is

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,I7,B:B,$J$4)
```

copied down. They pivot table is a lot more dynamic, though
[image]

Comment: Pivot tables is the way to go here most likely, but maybe the OP does not want to use them, for some reason.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, the most probable reason being that he does not know HOW to use them

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah, well in that case, the question should really be killed and the OP sent to Superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a clean way of doing this without reworking some of your data.  One approach would be to use `VLOOKUP` on a concatenation of the option number and item name.  Change your `Sheet2` data to this:

```
|------------|-------|--------|--------|
|OptionConcat|Option |Item    | Price  |
|------------|-------|--------|--------|
| 2-Banana   |   2   | Banana |  30    |
|------------|-------|--------|--------|
| 2-MANGO    |   2   | MANGO  |  80    |
|------------|-------|--------|--------|
| 2-ORANGE   |   2   | ORANGE |  100   |
|------------|-------|--------|--------|
| 2-RICE     |   2   | RICE   |  20    |
|------------|-------|--------|--------|
```

Now in the `B2` cell of `Sheet1` use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B$1&"-"&A2, Sheet2!$A$2:$D$100,4,0)
```

You may copy this formula down the `B` column.  And you would need to adjust the `Sheet2!` range in the `VLOOKUP` formula to cover the appropriate range of data.

Comment: Maybe you're overthinking this, Tim

Comment: @teylyn Perhaps, coming from a data/database background.  The fundamental problem is to do a lookup based on an item and option.  If we were only lookup up one thing, then `VLOOKUP` would be the way to go.  Hence, I offer an alternative.

Comment: Where does all that Vlookup need come from? The OP just wants to summarize by option number, hence pivot table or Sumifs. Perfectly doable with the current data structure.